# MATLAB: How to copy a handle object as quickly as possible

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm wondering how I can copy (and maybe delete) handle objects within MATLAB.

I am currently coding a solver for large systems of equations using MATLAB and an add-on called CPLEX. This solver essentially involves creating CPLEX handle objects and then solving them using a solve method as follows:

```
P = Cplex() %Create a Cplex object
%Code to specify the Cplex parameters
P.solve() %solve the Cplex object
```

In the code above, P is a MATLAB Handle Object that belongs to the Cplex() class. It stores a structure of matrices that relate to the factors of their equations.

The main issue that I am running is that I have to "solve" the same CPLEX object numerous times and I would like to do this in parallel, using a parfor loop. Unfortunately, the parfor loop in MATLAB requires transparency, since multiple threads cannot work on the same object.

I've thought of several ways around this: previously, I created and setup the Cplex() file within the parfor loop (this turns out to be slower than a single thread implementation); I also tried saving the object to disk and loading it up within the parfor loop (again too slow). Now I'd like to see if I could copy the object (either within the parfor loop, or outside of it). Unfortunately, however, there is no built-in "copy" function for Cplex objects and I would have to code something like that myself.

Essentially what I would like to do boils down to:

```
P = Cplex() %creates Cplex object
%Setup Cplex object

Q = cell(1,n) %create a container for Cplex objects

parfor 1:n

Q{i} = P.copy %create a copy of P and label it as Q{i}
Q{i}.solve()
Q{i} = [] %delete Cplex object (for memory purposes /preferable, but not necessary)

end
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, how does solving it multiple times change the outcome? Is the solver stochastic?

Comment: Actually the system of equations has a number of random parameters, and I need to solve it for each different combination of random parameters. What will eventually happen is that I will create a Cplex() object outside of the parfor loop, and then copy it/substitute in the random parameters within the parfor loop.

Comment: A few other questions as I try to understand what you need here... 1) Is the function call `Cplex()` that creates the object expensive? 2) Once you set the parameters (or however it is set up), will `a=Cplex()` and `b=Cplex()` represent the same system? 3) Do `a` and `b` have the same handles?

Comment: @yoda 1) The function/constructor call Cplex() is relatively expensive, in that building it from scratch and setting it up within the parfor loops essentially reduces all the time savings from the parallel processing. 2)/3) Not exactly sure about the question here, a = Cplex() will create a CPLEX object that can be accessed using a. b = a will simply create another pointer to the same CPLEX object, while b = Cplex() will create an entirely different CPLEX object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have CPLEX and since I cannot replicate your code, please try the following suggestion and let me know if it works (or if you get an error, what the error is).

Try defining `Q` outside of the `parfor` loop as

```
Q=arrayfun(@(x)P.copy,1:n,'UniformOutput',false);
```

This should create a cell as you had earlier and you can access it as `Q{i}` and should save you some time (because if you're worried about memory issues that you delete each element after processing, then copying it might involve some time overhead too).

Comment: The issue is that P does not have a copy method so P.copy wouldn't work in this case. My broader question is how I can add that to the class definition.

Comment: @Berk: Ah, then just try it without the `.copy` i.e., `arrayfun(@(x)P,1:n,...` That should assign the object `P` to each cell in `Q` which can then be accessed as `Q{i}`

Comment: So that won't work either because P is essentially behaves like a pointer to a CPlex() object. So Q = P will create a copy of the pointer, but not a copy of the object.

Comment: @Berk: I see... Do you know of an equivalent object in MATLAB and their toolboxes that behaves like your `Cplex` object? I ask because I'd like to fiddle with some code on my computer and see what works. Right now I'm just shooting blind.

Comment: I cannot think about an equivalent object in MATLAB, though when I create a = Cplex(), MATLAB refers to "a" as a a "handle class" so anything else that is a handle class should behave similarly.

Comment: @Berk: Ok, perhaps we might have a way here. There's a `copyobj` function that copies graphics objects to a parent object (see `help copyobj`). So for instance, if I wanted to make 3 copies of a graphics handle `a` parented under `b`, I'd do `c=copyobj([a,a,a],b)`. All the elements of `c` will have different pointers to identical objects, so it will be usable in `parfor`. Now the question is can this be modified/used with your object. Could you check if your Cplex object has a `parent` property and a `children` property? What do you get if you do `get(a,'Parent')` and `get(a,'Children')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's basically 3 possibilities, depending on the implementation details of CPLex:

1. Write a copy-function: This should work if all important properties of CPlex are publicly writable - this is basically what `copyobj` is for graphics-objects.
2. Subclass CPlex into `MyCPlex` and implement a copy-method. This should work as long as none of the important properties are `private`.
3. If there are private properties, than you'd either have to change those to protected and go with solution no. 2 or simply implement a copy-function as a method within CPlex.

Given that the constructor is expensive CPU-time wise, 2. or 3. might be the better version since you might have to implement an empty constructor: One that does simply return a object handle without all the internal initialization stuff.
The implementation details for copy should be straight forward - setting all properties of the copy-object to the values of the original object:
In it's naive version:

```
copyObj = CPlex();
props = {'propA', 'propB', ...}; % list of a all non-dependent, non-constant properties
for i=1:numel(props)
     copyObj.(props{i}) = originalObj.(props{i});
end
```

Depending on the complexity of the CPlex internals things might of course be somewhat more complicated...